# ValueError: shapes (7,200) and (1,1) not aligned: 200 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two ndarray x,y
the shape of x is (7,200) and the shape of y is (200,1)
but when I use matmul I got error said the shape of y is (1,1)

I've tried use matrix rather than ndarray, but get the same result

```py
def solve(X,Y):
    x = np.asmatrix(X)
    x = np.transpose(x)
    x = np.insert(x,0,1,axis=1)
    xt = x.T
    xtx = np.matmul(xt,x)
    y = np.asmatrix(Y)
    y = np.transpose(y)
    print('y',y.shape)
    pinv = np.linalg.pinv(xtx)
    print('pinv',pinv.shape)
    print('xt',xt.shape)
    z = np.matmul(pinv,xt)
    print('z',z.shape)
    B = np.matmul(z, y)
    print('B',B.shape)
    return B
```

```
('y', (200, 1))
('pinv', (8, 8))
('xt', (8, 200))
('z', (8, 200))
('B', (8, 1))


Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "project1.py", line 79, in <module>
    Z = X*B+resi
  File "/home/yiming/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 226, in __rmul__

return N.dot(other, self)

ValueError: shapes (7,200) and (1,1) not aligned: 200 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code that turns this into a [mcve]?

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I've edit my post and use the matrix version of y, the shape of y has became (200,1), but when I use matmul, I still get the same error

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is because of `np.matmul(pinv,xt)` - what's the shape of `xt`?

Comment: You'll probably still want to add a little bit more code so that people can see things going wrong. If this goes wrong for (7,200) and (200,1) it should also go wrong for (1,2) and (2,1), which are trivial to hard code as inputs and make it much easier to `print()` at every line so you can verify the shapes dont'/do change appropriately.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans the program need to read a data file, I may not publish it on the internet, but I can show you the output of y.

Comment: But you're not asking a question about your program, you're asking about your _function_, and that does not rely on files _at all_: creating an [mcve] means adding "just enough code to only run the one thing, with everything that can be hardcoded, hardcoded", so your full program would start with the numpy imports, then `X = ....` and `Y = ...` and then immediately call `solve(X,Y)` and that's basically it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This question is entirely reproducible, I'm not sure what other information it is you seek

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I was being too subtle, apparently: when asked to make a [mcve] that is in part to improve the reproducibility of the code in question, but it's _by far_ more important that someone goes through the motions of making the MCVE themselves because 99% of the time, _that exercise_ lets people discover exactly what's wrong themselves, simply because they're now trying to remove as much code as they can, and hardcode things to minimal data, and looking at their code with a far more critical mindset.

Comment: @YimingSun add a `print(B)` before returning, to verify that `B` is also the shape it should have been.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans A fair principle, though not suitable for this question - whose complexity is 'minimal' to begin with, so we may as well close the question and tell the user to figure it out. It _wouldn't_ be minimally-reproducible if shapes weren't provided - but they were.

Comment: Just because you spotted the problem does not make "asking people who just started posting to SO to run through the appropriate motions" any less valuable a lesson for them, as well as future visitors of the site.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the shape of B is (8,1) which is make sense, but the shape of y became (1,1) in the matmul, which is really wired

Comment: @YimingSun Remember to also look at answers other people have posted. OverLordGoldDragon has shown you what might be wrong, please see if they're right and if they are, upvote them and accept their answer.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just noticed the shown error is elsewhere entirely, which _does_ make the problem not minimally-reproducible - my mistake. Though it's fairly close

Comment: @YimingSun, what is the output of `print(X.shape, resi.shape)` if you run it right before line 79?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I figure out the issue, I used wrong way to call this function. I was using numpy.lstsq which returns multiple attribute. When I call the solve function, the format is like     B = solve(x,y)[0]     which causes this error. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to troubleshoot by printing shapes at every step:

```py
def solve(X,Y):
    x = np.asmatrix(X);          print(1, x.shape)
    x = np.transpose(x);         print(2, x.shape)
    x = np.insert(x,0,1,axis=1); print(3, x.shape)
    xt = x.T;                    print(4, xt.shape)
    xtx = np.matmul(xt,x);       print(5, xtx.shape)
    y = np.asmatrix(Y);          print(6, y.shape)
    y = np.transpose(y);         print(7, y.shape)
    pinv = np.linalg.pinv(xtx);  print(8, pinv.shape)
    pre_B = np.matmul(pinv,xt);  print(9, pre_B.shape, y.shape)
    B = np.matmul(pre_B, y)
    return B

## OUTPUT:
# 1 (7, 200)
# 2 (200, 7)
# 3 (200, 8)
# 4 (8, 200)
# 5 (8, 8)
# 6 (200, 1)
# 7 (1, 200)
# 8 (8, 8)
# 9 (8, 200) (1, 200)  <-- PROBLEM
```

**SOLUTION**: transpose `y` before the last `matmul` - then inner dimensions agree: `(8, 200) x (200, 1)` - and the final output shape will be `(8, 1)`:

```py
B = np.matmul(np.matmul(pinv,xt), y.T)
return B
```

Comment: The issue is in my output, #7 is (200,1), and #9 is (8,200) (200,1), but the error said in np.matmul, (7,200) and (1,1) not aligned